# Enable Robot Detection in 10.1 Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

After upgrading from 9.3 to 10.1, the 'Robot detection enabled' checkbox is uncheackable in form settings. Compared with [docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/93/sitecore-experience-platform/work-with-robot-detection-for-forms.html):

- Xdb enabled
- XdbTracking enabled
- AutoDetectBots enabled
- `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` is used on the layout

What else should I check to make it configurable?

[image]

Comment: did you check if xdb is working properly? maybe some xconnect ssl certificates are not configured fine and it cannot enable the robot detection

Comment: Marketing apps work fine, see some data there, no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 factors which have impact on the checkbox:

- `Xdb.Enabled` setting
- `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` setting
- `Analytics.AutoDetectBots` setting
- and result of `XdbSettings.HasValidLicense` call.

If I remember correctly, if you can open `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard` url without errors, that means that license is valid for xDB.

Have you changed any of the settings or license file after you tried Forms Editor for the first time? Maybe it's cached that checkbox should be disabled?

You can try the following url
`/formbuilder/load?id=&sc_formmode=new&sc_formlang=en&sc_site=shell&_=SOME_RANDOM_VALUE` and see the source of the response. It's not easy to read it but you should see something like

> `isRobotDetectionAvailable&quot;:true,&quot;`

or `false`.

If you see `true` in response, try new incognito browser or potentially even recycle Sitecore.

I checked that in Sitecore 10.1.1 `FormViewModel` depends on `IRobotDetection`. Check in showconfig if you have an implementation of `IRobotDetection` registered, most probably like that:

```
<register 
  serviceType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Tracking.IRobotDetection, Sitecore.ExperienceForms"
  implementationType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Analytics.Tracking.RobotDetection, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Analytics"
  lifetime="Transient"
  patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Tracker.config"/>
```

In Sitecore 10.1.0 there is no `IRobotDetection`. Instead there is `RobotDetectionHelper` which uses the following code:

```
public static bool IsRobotDetectionAvailable => 
  Settings.GetBoolSetting("Xdb.Enabled", false) && 
  Settings.GetBoolSetting("Xdb.Tracking.Enabled", false) && 
  Settings.GetBoolSetting("Analytics.AutoDetectBots", false);
```

You may create a test page or just try it in debug to see what are the values of those setting in your web app and which of them is causing issues.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the settings are enabled. And I do see data in ExpAnalytics app... Seeing false here, even in incognito: `isRobotDetectionAvailable&quot;:false,&quot;`

Comment: No typos in setting names? Have you checked showconfig if none of them are overwritten?

Comment: I added one more thing you can check in showconfig to my answer

Comment: Yep... looks like that is the issue. The RobotDetection registration appeared in 10.1.1 and 10.1.2 but it does not exist in 10.1.0 Initial Release. Thanks Marek!

Comment: I'm based on 10.1.0 where there is no Robot Detection neither in config, nor in assemblies... But I do see missing CI registration exception..

Comment: @SerhiiShushliapin See yet another edit in my answer

Comment: My bad, I've got mix between 10.1.0 and 10.1.1 versions. I'll get back with results if switching to the proper version fixes the checkbox. Thanks for your efforts, Marek!